# Secure Messaging Implementation in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, apdu, ecdh

After establishing PACE PIN authentication, I am trying to implement secure messaging to be able to send secure APDU commands. I based my implementation on the ICAO 9303 part 11 manual, chapter 9.8, page 63 : https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf,

and on this Java code that I used : https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java, as well as on a log from the PlatinumReader where secure messaging has already been implemented.
Here is my code:
**the method for calculating the APDU**:

```
 public string chipherAPDU(string apdu, string keyEnc, string keyMac)
   {
       string chipherApdu = "";

       byte[] apduBytes = StringToByteArray(apdu);
       byte[] KeyENC = StringToByteArray(keyEnc);
       byte[] KeyMAC = StringToByteArray(keyMac);
       byte[] secureMessagingSSC = StringToByteArray("00000000000000000000000000000001");
       SecureMessaging sm = new SecureMessaging(KeyMAC, KeyENC);
       chipherApdu = byteToHexStr ( sm.encrypt(apduBytes, secureMessagingSSC) );
       return chipherApdu;
   }
```

class SecureMessaging :

```
  internal class SecureMessaging
  {

          private readonly byte[] NULL = new byte[] { 0x00 };
          private const byte PAD = 0x80;
          private readonly byte[] secureMessagingSSC;
          private readonly byte[] keyMAC;
          private readonly byte[] keyENC;           

          public SecureMessaging(byte[] keyMAC, byte[] keyENC)
          {
              this.keyENC = keyENC;
              this.keyMAC = keyMAC;

              secureMessagingSSC = new byte[16];
          }

          public byte[] encrypt(byte[] apdu)
          {
              incrementSSC(secureMessagingSSC);
              byte[] commandAPDU = encrypt(apdu, secureMessagingSSC);
              incrementSSC(secureMessagingSSC);

              return commandAPDU;
          }

          public byte[] encrypt(byte[] apdu, byte[] secureMessagingSSC)
          {
              MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
              CardCommandAPDU cAPDU = new CardCommandAPDU(apdu);

              if (cAPDU.isSecureMessaging())
              {
                  throw new ArgumentException("Malformed APDU.");
              }

              byte[] data = cAPDU.data;
              byte[] header = cAPDU.header;
              int lc = cAPDU.lc;
              int le = cAPDU.le;

              if (data.Length > 0)
              {
                  data = pad(data, 16);
                  using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                  {
                      aes.Key = keyENC;
                      aes.IV = getCipherIV(secureMessagingSSC);
                      aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                      aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                      ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                      byte[] encryptedData = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);

                      outputStream.Write(new byte[] { 0x01 }, 0, 1);
                      outputStream.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
                  }
              }

              return outputStream.ToArray();
          }

          public byte[] decrypt(byte[] response)
          {
              if (response.Length < 12)
              {
                  throw new ArgumentException("Malformed Secure Messaging APDU.");
              }
              return decrypt(response, secureMessagingSSC);
          }

          private byte[] decrypt(byte[] response, byte[] secureMessagingSSC)
          {
              MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
              byte[] statusBytes = new byte[2];
              byte[] dataObject = null;
              byte[] macObject = new byte[8];                

              return outputStream.ToArray();
          }

          public static void incrementSSC(byte[] ssc)
          {
              for (int i = ssc.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
              {
                  ssc[i]++;
                  if (ssc[i] != 0)
                  {
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }

          // Other methods omitted for brevity
          private byte[] pad(byte[] data, int blockSize)
          {
              byte[] result = new byte[data.Length + (blockSize - data.Length % blockSize)];
              Array.Copy(data, 0, result, 0, data.Length);
              result[data.Length] = PAD;

              return result;
          }

          private byte[] getCipherIV(byte[] smssc)
          {
              using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
              {
                  aes.Key = keyENC;
                  aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                  aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                  ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, null);
                  return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(smssc, 0, smssc.Length);
              }
          }
  }
```

**class CardCommandAPDU** :

```
  public class CardCommandAPDU
  {
      public byte[] header = new byte[4];
      public int le = -1;
      public int lc = -1;
      public byte[] data;
      public CardCommandAPDU(byte[] commandAPDU)
      {
          Array.Copy(commandAPDU, 0, header, 0, 4);
          setBody(copy(commandAPDU, 4, commandAPDU.Length - 4));
      }



      /**
       * Définit le corps (LE, DATA, LC) de l'APDU.
       *
       * @param body Corps de l'APDU
       */
      public void setBody(byte[] body)
      {
          /*
           * Cas 1. : |CLA|INS|P1|P2|
           * Cas 2. : |CLA|INS|P1|P2|LE|
           * Cas 2.1: |CLA|INS|P1|P2|EXTLE|
           * Cas 3. : |CLA|INS|P1|P2|LC|DATA|
           * Cas 3.1: |CLA|INS|P1|P2|EXTLC|DATA|
           * Cas 4. : |CLA|INS|P1|P2|LC|DATA|LE|
           * Cas 4.1: |CLA|INS|P1|P2|EXTLC|DATA|LE|
           * Cas 4.2: |CLA|INS|P1|P2|LC|DATA|EXTLE|
           * Cas 4.3: |CLA|INS|P1|P2|EXTLC|DATA|EXTLE|
           */
          try
          {
              using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(body))
              {
                  int length = (int)stream.Length;

                  // Nettoyage
                  lc = -1;
                  le = -1;
                  data = new byte[0];

                  if (length == 0)
                  {
                      // Cas 1. : |CLA|INS|P1|P2|
                  }
                  else if (length == 1)
                  {
                      // Cas 2 |CLA|INS|P1|P2|LE|
                      le = stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
                  }
                  else if (length < 65536)
                  {
                      int tmp = stream.ReadByte();

                      if (tmp == 0)
                      {
                          // Cas 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 4.3
                          if (stream.Length < 3)
                          {
                              // Cas 2.1 |CLA|INS|P1|P2|EXTLE|
                              le = (stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF) << 8 | stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              // Cas 3.1, 4.1, 4.3
                              lc = (stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF) << 8 | stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF;

                              data = new byte[lc];
                              stream.Read(data, 0, lc);

                              if (stream.Length == 1)
                              {
                                  // Cas 4.1 |CLA|INS|P1|P2|EXTLC|DATA|LE|
                                  le = stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
                              }
                              else if (stream.Length == 2)
                              {
                                  // Cas 4.3 |CLA|INS|P1|P2|EXTLC|DATA|EXTLE|
                                  le = (stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF) << 8 | stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
                              }
                              else if (stream.Length == 3)
                              {
                                  if (stream.ReadByte() == 0)
                                  {
                                      // Cas 4.3 |CLA|INS|P1|P2|EXTLC|DATA|EXTLE|
                                      le = (stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF) << 8 | stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF;
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      throw new ArgumentException("APDU malformée.");
                                  }
                              }
                              else if (stream.Length > 3)
                              {
                                  throw new ArgumentException("APDU malformée.");
                              }
                          }
                      }
                      else if (tmp > 0)
                      {
                          // Cas 3, 4, 4.2
                          lc = tmp & 0xFF;
                          data = new byte[lc];
                          stream.Read(data, 0, lc);

                          if (stream.Length == 1)
                          {
                              // Cas 4 |CLA|INS|P1|P2|LC|DATA|LE|
                              setLE((byte)stream.ReadByte());
                          }
                          else if (stream.Length == 3)
                          {
                              // Cas 4.2 |CLA|INS|P1|P2|LC|DATA|EXTLE|
                              stream.ReadByte(); // Ignorer le premier octet
                              setLE((short)((stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF) << 8 | stream.ReadByte() & 0xFF));
                          }
                          else if (stream.Length == 2 || stream.Length > 3)
                          {
                              throw new ArgumentException("APDU malformée.");
                          }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          throw new ArgumentException("APDU malformée.");
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      throw new ArgumentException("APDU malformée.");
                  }
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Exception", e);
          }
      }

      /**
       * Définit le champ de longueur attendue (LE) de l'APDU.
       *
       * @param le Champ de longueur attendue (LE)
       */
      public void setLE(short le)
      {
          if (le == (short)0x0000)
          {
              setLE(65536);
          }
          else
          {
              setLE((int)le & 0xFFFF);
          }
      }

      /**
       * Définit le champ de longueur attendue (LE) de l'APDU.
       *
       * @param le Champ de longueur attendue (LE)
       */
      public void setLE(int le)
      {
          if (le < 0 || le > 65536)
          {
              throw new ArgumentException("La longueur doit être comprise entre '1' et '65535'.");
          }
          else
          {
              this.le = le;
          }
      }

              /**
       * Copie une plage de bytes.
       *
       * @param input l'entrée
       * @param offset l'offset
       * @param length la longueur
       * @return le tableau de bytes
       */
      public static byte[] copy(byte[] input, int offset, int length)
      {
          if (input == null)
          {
              return null;
          }
          byte[] tmp = new byte[length];
          Array.Copy(input, offset, tmp, 0, length);
          return tmp;
      }


      public  bool isSecureMessaging()
      {
          return (header[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0C;
      }

  }
```

Here are the data from the PlatinumReader that I used where it works fine, and I'm trying to get the same result:

```
APDU: Request: 00 a4 04 0c 07 a0 00 00 02 47 10 01          
GENERIC P7896 T36084 : APDU: SMRequest - 00000000000000000000000000000001
0c a4 04 0c 1d 87 11 01 a9 48 e4 f1 a8 23 56 c1
1c f1 a6 a0 b1 8d 0c 8f 8e 08 71 b6 0b b9 3b 7a 
f1 08 00
```

Here is the test i do by using the same values :

```
 string apduSM = chipherAPDU("00a4040c07a0000002471001", "3d7155f3791c313c2924f51ae60f1ac9" , "b5feb9488f17be03e54c7d80907e8a1f");
  addLogMsg("ADPU SM : " + apduSM);
```

And here is my result :

```
ADPU SM : 01A948E4F1A82356C11CF1A6A0B18D0C8F
```

The Keys used are ephemeral so i can post them and it just a testing phase:

**Key: K_MAC - derived MAC key (K_MAC [PACE])
b5 fe b9 48 8f 17 be 03 e5 4c 7d 80 90 7e 8a 1f**

**Key: K_Enc - derived encryption key (K_Enc [PACE])
3d 71 55 f3 79 1c 31 3c 29 24 f5 1a e6 0f 1a c9**

And here is the test : https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3z7P1

I have part of the encrypted data, I should have a structure like: Header Lc' '87' L '01' 'Encrypted Data' Le'
where header is :  **0c a4 04 0c**

Comment: Are you aware that your result is included in the reference data 0ca4040c1d8711**01a948e4f1a82356c11cf1a6a0b18d0c8f**8e0871b60bb93b7af10800? I'm only asking because you don't mention it at all.

Comment: Yes, I know! Sorry, I will specify it. That's why I think I made a mistake in the formula.
What I want is the entire chain, I understood that the result I obtained is just the encoding of the data.
The header itself is left as is, changing the CLA to CLA = 0x0c and adapting the Le by Lc' based on what got on encrypted data.
Header Lc'  ‘87’ L ‘01’ Encrypted Data‘ Le
Where header is : 0c a4 04 0c

Comment: The reference data seems to have some similarities with those in the description (header, DO87, DO8E). The latter is associated with a MAC, which seems to be implemented in the Java code, but not in the C# code, which may be why this part is missing in your case. I'm not familiar with the protocol though, so this is just speculation.

Comment: You might want to check the implementation of `StringToByteArray` to make sure it uses the correct encoding. Also, are the `@param` notes consumed by a tool? If not, consider using standard C# _XML Comments_ (which are consumable)

Comment: It looks to me as if the porting of the Java code into the C# code is incomplete. Besides the MAC, e.g. the implementation of the `TLV` class that performs ASN.1 encodings is missing. This might lead to errors, e.g. missing length specifications and consequently to an incorrect MAC (even if it were implemented).

Comment: Yes, I see that, i'm trying to implement the missing code in the encrypt method and the TLV class, Tag, and TagLengthValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the result generated by the C# code and the reference data is due to an incomplete porting of the Java reference code to C#.
In particular, the implementation of the MAC and the implementation of the `TLV` class that performs ASN.1/DER encodings are missing. If the Java code is ported *completely* to C#, the reference data can be reproduced.

In the following C# code, the `encrypt(byte[], byte[])` method has been supplemented with the functionalities from the Java code that are required to generate the reference data (the corresponding line of the Java reference code is specified in the C# code):

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Macs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;

...

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] apdu, byte[] secureMessagingSSC)
{
    CardCommandAPDU cAPDU = new CardCommandAPDU(apdu);
    
    if (cAPDU.isSecureMessaging())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Malformed APDU.");
    }
    
    byte[] data = cAPDU.data;
    byte[] header = cAPDU.header;
    int lc = cAPDU.lc;
    int le = cAPDU.le;
    
    byte[] dataEncrypted = [];
    if (data.Length > 0)
    {
        data = pad(data, 16);
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = keyENC;
            aes.IV = getCipherIV(secureMessagingSSC);
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            dataEncrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
    
            // Add padding indicator 0x01 
            // Java code: https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java#L114
            dataEncrypted = [0x01, ..dataEncrypted];
    
            // ASN.1/DER (TLV) - encrypted data
            // Java code: https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java#L117
            dataEncrypted = [0x87, (byte)dataEncrypted.Length, ..dataEncrypted];
        }
    }
    
    // Write protected LE: skipped as le < 0
    // Java code: https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java#L123
    if (le >= 0)
    {
        // ...
    }
    
    // Indicate Secure Messaging 
    // Java code:   https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java#L137
    header[0] |= 0x0C;
    
    // Calculate MAC
    // Java code: https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java#L142
    byte[] mac = new byte[16];
    CMac cmac = getCMAC(secureMessagingSSC);
    byte[] paddedHeader = pad(header, 16);
    cmac.BlockUpdate(paddedHeader, 0, paddedHeader.Length);
    if (dataEncrypted.Length > 0)
    {
        byte[] paddedData = pad(dataEncrypted, 16);
        cmac.BlockUpdate(paddedData, 0, paddedData.Length);
    }
    cmac.DoFinal(mac, 0);
    mac = mac[..8];
    
    // ASN.1/DER (TLV) - MAC
    // Java code: https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java#L160
    mac = [0x8e, (byte)mac.Length, ..mac];
    
    // Concate encrypted data and MAC 
    // Java code: https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java#L163 
    byte[] secureData = [..dataEncrypted, ..mac];
    
    // Add header and footer
    // Java code: https://github.com/ecsec/open-ecard/blob/master/ifd/ifd-protocols/pace/src/main/java/org/openecard/ifd/protocol/pace/SecureMessaging.java#L165
    byte[] secureCommand = [..header, (byte)secureData.Length, ..secureData, 0x00];
    
    return secureCommand;
}
        
private CMac getCMAC(byte[] smssc)
{
    CMac cmac = new CMac(new AesEngine());
    cmac.Init(new KeyParameter(keyMAC));
    cmac.BlockUpdate(smssc, 0, smssc.Length);

    return cmac;
}
```

If these methods are replaced/added in the posted C# code, the reference data `0x0ca4040c1d871101a948e4f1a82356c11cf1a6a0b18d0c8f8e0871b60bb93b7af10800` can be reproduced.

Please note that the above changes are *incomplete* and only implement the functionalities required for this *specific* reference data. For the C# code to work *in general*, the `encrypt(byte[], byte[])` method from the Java code must be *completely* migrated!